# Drag and Drop with Drag Adorner

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, adorner

i used a drag adorner to clone the image of my labels ( drag target ) but however now i couldn't drop my label into my textbox ,

this is the code i have used ( u might see theres previewdragover , i wrote e.Handled = true in previewdragover but doesn't help ) i have also set tbox.AllowDrop to true :

TextBox :

```
  tbox.PreviewDrop += new DragEventHandler(tbox_PreviewDrop);
  tbox.PreviewDragOver += new DragEventHandler(tbox_PreviewDragOver);
```

Handlers for textbox :

```
   protected void tbox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Text = string.Empty; // Empty the textbox from previous answer.
        (sender as TextBox).Background = Brushes.White;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Label ( drag target ) :

```
             Label lbl = new Label();
             lbl.Content = s;
             lbl.Width = Double.NaN;
             lbl.Height = 40;
             lbl.FontSize = 19;
             lbl.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(lbl_MouseDown);
             lbl.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(lbl_MouseMove);
             lbl.GiveFeedback += new GiveFeedbackEventHandler(lbl_GiveFeedback);
             lbl.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(lbl_MouseUp); 
             wrapPanel2.Children.Add(lbl);
```

Handlers for label :

```
        private void lbl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        startPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

    }

    private void lbl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {


            var source = sender as UIElement;
            Label lbl = sender as Label;
            Point current = e.GetPosition(this);
            Vector diff = startPoint - current;

            if (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {

                adorner = new DragAdorner(lbl, e.GetPosition(lbl));
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(lbl).Add(adorner);

                var dragData = new DataObject(this);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(source, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(lbl).Remove(adorner);
            }
            startPoint = current;
        }
    }

    private void lbl_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (adorner != null)
        {
            Label lbl = sender as Label;
            var pos = lbl.PointFromScreen(GetMousePosition());
            adorner.UpdatePosition(pos);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref Win32Point pt);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct Win32Point
    {
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
    };

    public static Point GetMousePosition()
    {
        Win32Point w32Mouse = new Win32Point();
        GetCursorPos(ref w32Mouse);
        return new Point(w32Mouse.X, w32Mouse.Y);
    }

    private Point startPoint;
    private DragAdorner adorner;
```

Now i can drag the labels with the labels following my cursor but i can't drop them in any textbox.

-----EDIT------------

I have put a dragenter for textbox like this :

```
       private void tbox_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == e.Source)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

    }
```

Still not working tho.

i'll add the DragAdorner.cs here that i've used ( i got it from some chinese web )  :

```
public class DragAdorner : Adorner {

public DragAdorner(UIElement adornedElement, Point offset)

    : base(adornedElement) {

    this.offset = offset;

    vbrush = new VisualBrush(AdornedElement);
    vbrush.Opacity = .7;

}



public void UpdatePosition(Point location) {

    this.location = location;

    this.InvalidateVisual();

}



protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc) {

    var p = location;

    p.Offset(-offset.X, -offset.Y);

    dc.DrawRectangle(vbrush, null, new Rect(p, this.RenderSize));

}



private Brush vbrush;

private Point location;

private Point offset;
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your drag adorner is always on top. When you try to drop your label it drops on the adorner instead of the underlying component.

To avoid this add the following line to the constructor of the DragAdorner.

> IsHitTestVisible = false;

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somewhat different to my working example, but I think that I can see your problem. In my code, I have a method called `UpdateDragDropEffects`. This method takes in an object of type `DragEventArgs` named `e` and updates the `e.Effects` property dependent on the value of the `e.AllowedEffects` property and also whether I have a valid `ICommand` instance to call and whether the data is of the expected type, etc.

This method is called (and the `DragEventArgs` object passed from) two typical drag and drop methods; `DragTargetPreviewDrop` (handles the `PreviewDrop` event) and `AdornedUIElementPreviewDragOver` (handles the `PreviewDragOver` event). Setting the `e.Effects` property of the `DragEventArgs` object tells the system whether the current drag opearation is valid and should continue or not... not setting it, or setting it to `DragDropEffects.None` will have the effect of not displaying any valid drop targets.

The [Drag and Drop Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx) page at MSDN has code examples that should also help you. The `Enabling an Element to be a Drop Target` section has example code that shows what I have described.

You could also have other problems, but come back and update if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Before i use adorner , my drag-and-drop works well . I had previewdrop and dragover in my textbox but do i really need DragEnter handler for my textbox? because it says Occurs when input system reports an underlying event with this element as a drag target , my textbox is a drop target...

Comment: Is it something got to do with my DragAdorner.cs ? because sometimes when i drag the target and i move really quick with my mouse , cursor will sometimes show the symbol to drop , but most of the time is the default cursor which is the black circle with a line in the middle

Comment: I still think it's because you are not setting `e.Effects` to a valid value... you added an edit, but then set `e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;`. This is like cancelling your drag and drop operation.  You need to set it to `DragDropEffects.Copy` or `DragDropEffects.Move` dependent upon your wishes and the value of the `e.AllowedEffects` property of the `DragEventArgs` instance. Also, I don't know why you put it into the `tbox_PreviewDragEnter` handler... I said to call it from either the `PreviewDrop` or `PreviewDragOver` event handlers (*of the drop target*).

Comment: Another thing... is that your whole `DragAdorner` class? It looks absolutely *nothing* like my one. Where is your override for the `VisualChildrenCount` property, `MeasureOverride`, `ArrangeOverride` and `GetVisualChild` methods? You can find a better example in this [WPF: Drag Drop Adorner](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/06/17/wpf-drag-drop-adorner/) article. This [Drag and Drop in WPF - Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43702/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF-Part-II) article should also help you (especially with `e.effects`).

Comment: I seen before your source code , i couldn't understand everything , the cs file is re-usable?

Comment: Just to be clear, that's not my code in those articles. I adapted some of the technique from the `WPF Control Development Unleashed` book and developed the rest myself with great pain and suffering. I actually found a [PDF version online](http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf) that you can read (from page 103). And yes, the `DragAdorner` class is supposed to be re-usable. My whole drag/drop functionality has been made using `Attached Properties` so it can be set up with just XAML and is *all* re-usable... you don't want to have to re-create it every time, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your Dragadorner with Point(-5,-5). (new DragAdorner(new Point(-5,-5));)

The drop Event seems to be thrown on the Adorner. If you add a drop handler to the Adorner youll see that it gets called when you release the mouse.

It seems that the Mouse pointer is over the Adorner and it takes it as Target.

Setting the offset to a Point so that the Adorner is not under the Mousepointer corrects that behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.